# Matlab: Fixing colormap to specified values when the solutions at specific value

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I solved the diffusion equation in 2D geometry with fixed boundary conditions and consumption term. How can I add to the colormap a new color (or dotted line on the 2D graph) specifying a certain level of the chemical concentration within the (x-y) graph ? For example, in this code my colormap goes from dark red to dark blue as the solutions change from 155 at the top to 24 at the bottom, how can I add a different color to the colormap showing the locations on the 2D graph where the solutions are 18?

```
c = 1e-1;
 a = 0;
 f = char('-22222*u./(2.2+u)');
 d = 1;

 xmin=0;xmax=0.575;ymin=0;ymax=0.05315;ymax2=0.073; 
 gdm = [3;4;xmin;xmax;xmax;xmin;ymax;ymax2;ymin;ymin];
 g = decsg(gdm, 'S1', ('S1')');
 hmax = .1; % element size
[p, e, t] = initmesh(g, 'Hmax', hmax);
[p,e,t] = refinemesh(g,p,e,t);
[p,e,t] = refinemesh(g,p,e,t);
[p,e,t] = refinemesh(g,p,e,t);
[p,e,t] = refinemesh(g,p,e,t);
[p,e,t] = refinemesh(g,p,e,t);
 % Create a pde entity for a PDE with a single dependent variable
numberOfPDE = 1;
pb = pde(numberOfPDE);
% Create a geometry entity
pg = pdeGeometryFromEdges(g);
bc1 = pdeBoundaryConditions(pg.Edges(1),'u',155);
bc2 = pdeBoundaryConditions(pg.Edges(2),'u',51);
bc3 = pdeBoundaryConditions(pg.Edges(3),'u',24);
bc4 = pdeBoundaryConditions(pg.Edges(4),'g',0);
pb.BoundaryConditions = [bc1,bc2,bc3,bc4];

u = pdenonlin(pb,p,e,t,c,a,f, 'jacobian', 'lumped');
figure;
pdeplot(p, e, t, 'xydata', u, 'contour', 'on', 'colormap', 'jet');
title 'Chemical Diffusion, Steady State Solution'
xlabel 'X-coordinate, meters'
ylabel 'Y-coordinate, meters'
```

Comment: Can you show us some code to reproduce what you've done so far?  I can't tell if this is a surface plot or a normal 2D graph.  This will inevitably close as we can't reproduce what you're trying to make.

Comment: This is my code, how to specify (using different color) the locations where the solutions in the 2D graph equal to 18? Thanks @rayryeng

Comment: use [`contour`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) (and may be look at the last example "_Display Single Contour Line_", although you may want to display more than one line later.